# Add function when getting queryset django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my view I get the popular articles by this variable:

```
popular_article_list = Article.objects.order_by('-votes')[:5]
```

Now in my model I have a `was_published_recently` function that looks like this:

```
def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```

So how do I combine the two to get the most popular articles in the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 2):

A queryset has no access to functions, since a `QuerySet` produces a query at the database side. The database does not know anything about these functions. It would also be quite inefficient, since it would mean first fetching all objects, and then filtering at the Django/Python level.

You can however filter a `QuerySet` with the objects with a `pub_date` between yesterday and today with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from datetime import timedelta

popular_article_list = Article.objects.filter(
    pub_date__range=(Now()-timedelta(days=1), Now())
).order_by('-votes')[:5]
```

You can further boost the efficiency by adding a database index on the `pub_date` field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```